# problems with awaitMessages() in user DMs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am creating a report function for my bot such that when called, it will DM the user asking for the report and when the user provides it, it will take the report and embed it in a predefined channel within the server.

```
message.author.send("Please send your report here in a single message below 1000 characters in length. Provide the tag of the User, Reason and Evidence(optional). This instance shall expire in 120 seconds")
    .then((rMsg) => {
        rMsg.channel.awaitMessages(res => res.content, {
            max: 1,
            time: 120000,
            errors: ['time']
        })
        .then((report) => {

            console.log(report);
            let dmrEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#8E5BC5')
            .setTitle('User Report (Type: DM)')
            .addField('Reporter :', `<@${message.author.id}> ID: ${message.author.id}`)
            .addField('Report Content:', `${report.content}`)
            .setFooter(message.createdAt);

            rMsg.channel.send('Your report has been received. You may be contacted for further information.');

            rChannel.send(dmrEmbed);

        }).catch(() => {
            rMsg.channel.send('This instance has expired.');
        });
    });

    return;
```

This code is exhibiting 2 main problems. It is supposed to accept input from the user in DM, yet when it dms the user the first message asking for the report, immediately after, it will post the 'your report has been received' message. When I console logged the `report`, I could see that the bot had taken it's own first message as the reply.

The second problem is, `report.content` returns `undefined` even though report has a content element with the message contained within it.

Comment: The first parameter of the the awaitMessages method is the filter, which should resolve to a boolean value. You need something like `awaitMessages(res => res.content && res.author.id != client.user.id ..`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small issues, lets go over them:

Issue 1:
[DMChannel#awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) parameters are:
[image: Docs]

So you need to add a proper filter to only accept messages from the reporter like:

```
rMsg.channel.awaitMessages(res => res.content && res.author.id == , {
```

This will make sure to only capature messages with content and from the reporter.

Issue 2: [DMChannel#awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) returns a Collection.
[image: Docs]

So instead of

```
.then((report) => {
```

use

```
.then((collected) => {
    const report = collected.first(); // This will return the proper message object.
```